# Why is Heroku not updating my Django app's code?

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, deployment

I have a Django blog deployed by Heroku, statics served with S3 Bucket. A few days ago I realised that my changes are not shown in the actual code when I inspect it with Chrome's Inspector tool. I pushed them to the git repo and to heroku master. This project is for my thesis, so it would be really important to resolve this problem. Thank you very much to spend your time helping me in advance.

This is one of my latest changes:
Added a paragraph to a django signup form that the user can view my Privacy Policy before signing up to my blog.
I attached the code from PyCharm:

```
{% extends 'default.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Signup</h1>
    <form class="site-form" action="/accounts/signup/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Signup">
    </form>
    <!-- Privacy Policy Link -->
    <p>By signing up, you agree to our <a href="https://www.termsfeed.com/live/d0e2bb42-feca-4abe-8051-afccfe402f6a">Privacy Policy</a>.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

The code from the actual website with Google's Inspector tool:

```
<form class="site-form" action="/accounts/signup/" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="1P17fSXi3R2ihBMd17GqUPmx2pIsL4c855BnGwrhTbenlx4sKQea1nJTuCK0Apei">
        <label for="id_username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" maxlength="150" autofocus="" required="" id="id_username" data-siid="si_input_0"><br><span class="helptext">Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.</span>
<label for="id_email">Email:</label><input type="email" name="email" required="" id="id_email" data-siid="si_input_1">
<label for="id_password1">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password1" autocomplete="new-password" required="" id="id_password1" data-siid="si_input_2"><br><span class="helptext"><ul><li>Your password can’t be too similar to your other personal information.</li><li>Your password must contain at least 8 characters.</li><li>Your password can’t be a commonly used password.</li><li>Your password can’t be entirely numeric.</li></ul></span>
<label for="id_password2">Password confirmation:</label><input type="password" name="password2" autocomplete="new-password" required="" id="id_password2" data-siid="si_input_3"><br><span class="helptext">Enter the same password as before, for verification.</span>
        <input type="submit" value="Signup">
    </form>
```

Here we can see that before the submit button, there isn't the Privacy policy line of code.

I checked the production code in heroku bash:

```
~/accounts/Templates/accounts $ cat signup.html
cat signup.html
{% extends 'default.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Signup</h1>
    <form class="site-form" action="/accounts/signup/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Signup">
    </form>
    <!-- Privacy Policy Link -->
    <p>By signing up, you agree to our <a href="https://www.termsfeed.com/live/d0e2bb42-feca-4abe-8051-afccfe402f6a">Privacy Policy</a>.</p>
{% endblock %}~/accounts/Templates/accounts $ ls
ls
login.html  signup.html
```

There were no problem with pushing and redeploying my app until a few days ago.

The url to my page is:http://www.moviefanblog.hu
I don't know if it is reachable outside of Hungary.

I tried collectstatic and nothing happened.

I tried to restart the dyno and redeploy master branch in heroku GUI.

Here we can see that every repo is synced:
[repos status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPt9Z.png)

Here is my settings.py:

```
import os
import django_heroku
import dj_database_url
from pathlib import Path
from decouple import config

SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 3600
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.moviefanblog.hu', 'moviefanblog.hu', 'moviefanblog.herokuapp.com', 'localhost',  '127.0.0.1']
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['www.moviefanblog.hu', 'moviefanblog.hu', 'moviefanblog.herokuapp.com', 'localhost',  '127.0.0.1']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'articles',
    'accounts',
    'storages',
    'boto3',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'blog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['Templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'blog.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
# STATIC_URL = '/static/'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ''
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ''
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'moviefanblog-storage'
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'eu-north-1'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
AWS_LOCATION = 'statics'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'statics'),
    )

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AWS_LOCATION}/'

# MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
## MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AWS_LOCATION}/'
## MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = 'https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
django_heroku.settings(locals())

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': ('%(asctime)s [%(process)d] [%(levelname)s] '
                       'pathname=%(pathname)s lineno=%(lineno)s '
                       'funcname=%(funcName)s %(message)s'),
            'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}
```

```
│   db.sqlite3
│   manage.py
│   Procfile
│   requirements.txt
│
├───.idea
│   │   .gitignore
│   │   blog.iml
│   │   misc.xml
│   │   modules.xml
│   │   vcs.xml
│   │   workspace.xml
│   │
│   └───inspectionProfiles
│           profiles_settings.xml
│
├───accounts
│   │   admin.py
│   │   apps.py
│   │   forms.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   tests.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   views.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───migrations
│   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   │
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   │           __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │
│   ├───Templates
│   │   └───accounts
│   │           login.html
│   │           signup.html
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│           admin.cpython-37.pyc
│           apps.cpython-37.pyc
│           models.cpython-37.pyc
│           urls.cpython-37.pyc
│           views.cpython-37.pyc
│           __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│
├───articles
│   │   admin.py
│   │   apps.py
│   │   forms.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   tests.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   views.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───migrations
│   │   │   0001_initial.py
│   │   │   0002_article_thumb.py
│   │   │   0003_alter_article_thumb.py
│   │   │   0004_alter_article_thumb.py
│   │   │   0005_article_author.py
│   │   │   0006_auto_20230301_1912.py
│   │   │   0007_auto_20230301_1916.py
│   │   │   0008_alter_article_thumb.py
│   │   │   0009_alter_article_title.py
│   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   │
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   │           0001_initial.cpython-37.pyc
│   │           0002_article_thumb.cpython-37.pyc
│   │           0003_alter_article_thumb.cpython-37.pyc
│   │           0004_alter_article_thumb.cpython-37.pyc
│   │           0005_article_author.cpython-37.pyc
│   │           0006_auto_20230301_1912.cpython-37.pyc
│   │           0007_auto_20230301_1916.cpython-37.pyc
│   │           0008_alter_article_thumb.cpython-37.pyc
│   │           0009_alter_article_title.cpython-37.pyc
│   │           __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │
│   ├───Templates
│   │   └───articles
│   │           article_create.html
│   │           article_details.html
│   │           article_form.html
│   │           article_list.html
│   │           pagination.html
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│           admin.cpython-37.pyc
│           apps.cpython-37.pyc
│           forms.cpython-37.pyc
│           models.cpython-37.pyc
│           urls.cpython-37.pyc
│           views.cpython-37.pyc
│           __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│
├───blog
│   │   asgi.py
│   │   settings.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   views.py
│   │   wsgi.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───Templates
│   │       about.html
│   │       default.html
│   │       home.html
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│           settings.cpython-37.pyc
│           urls.cpython-37.pyc
│           views.cpython-37.pyc
│           wsgi.cpython-37.pyc
│           __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│
├───media
│       Avengers_Endgame.jpg
│       A_Star_Is_Born.jpg
│       Battle_Angel_Alita.jpg
│       Battle_Angel_Alita_WEZ1cKm.jpg
│       default-movie.jpg
│       default-movie.png
│       Glass.jpg
│       Hair.jpg
│
├───statics
│   │   background.jpg
│   │   background.png
│   │   bootstrap.min.css
│   │   default-movie.png
│   │   favicon.ico
│   │   logo.png
│   │   logo2.png
│   │   logo3.jpg
│   │   logo3.png
│   │   logo4.png
│   │   logo5.png
│   │   logo6.png
│   │   slugify.js
│   │   stars.png
│   │   styles.css
│   │
│   └───movies
│           *Full of movie cover jpgs.*
│
└───Templates
    │   about.html
    │   default.html
    │   home.html
    │
    ├───accounts
    │       login.html
    │       signup.html
    │
    └───articles
            article_create.html
            article_details.html
            article_form.html
            article_list.html
            pagination.html
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Well, how are you deploying? Via git? GitHub integration?

Comment: I added my github repo to heroku and it deploys from it. But it turned out, that I have a problem with my file structure.

Comment: @Chris I have attached my file tree and my settings.py I think I have misconfigured the Templates folder. The app reads it from root/Templates. And I chenged the file in Accounts/Templates/accounts. How can I change the TEMPLATES = [ in settings.py to point to the right directory. But notice that I have separate Templates folder one in root/Articles, one in root/blog and one in root/Accounts. I'm a bit confused. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is deployment succeeding? If not, please also add your deploy logs.

Comment: @Chris, I'm sorry for the late answering, The deployment is successful. I can use my site perfectly and flawless